# Fatal error: Call to undefined function customerslist() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\application\controllers\Customer.php on line 25

Tags: php, codeigniter

AM trying to connect `modal` in `controller` but it showing error like

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function customerslist() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\application\controllers\Customer.php on line 25
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function customerslist()
>
> Filename: controllers/Customer.php
>
> Line Number: 25
>
> Backtrace:

My code is following:

**controller : Customer.php**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Customer extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){

        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('admin');
        $this->load->model('customers');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        if($this->session->userdata('Admin')==false)
        {
            redirect('login');
        }
        else
        {
            $data['title'] = "Customer";
            $data['customerlist'] = $this->customers>customerslist();
            $this->load->view('customer',$data);
        }
    }
}
```

**Modal: Customers.php**

```
<?php 
class Customers extends CI_Model {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
    //view all Customers
    function customerslist()
    {
        $res = $this->db->get('customers_list');
        if($res->num_rows() >0){
        foreach($res->result_array() as $row){
            $customerlist[] = $row;
        }
            return $customerlist;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //view all Customers
}
```

How can i fix this issues?
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Where do you actually create an instance of `Customers` and assign it to the `$customers` field of your controller?

Comment: @localheinz:  Thanks for reply where would i assign `$customers`. Sorry am new in `codeigniter`

Comment: @localheinz CodeIgniter does this for you when `$this->load->model('customers');` is called in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `-` in `$this->customers>customerslist();`

This should be `$this->customers->customerslist();`